# What is /usr/local/bin?

Tags: executable, directory-structure

Before today, I've used the terminal to a limited extent of moving in and out of directories and changing the dates of files using the `touch` command. I had realised the full extent of the terminal after installing a fun script on Mac and having to `chmod 755` the file to make it executable afterwards.

I'd like to know what `/usr/local/bin` is, though. `/usr/`, I assume, is the user of the computer. I'm not sure why `/local/` is there, though. It obviously stands for the local computer, but since it's on the computer (or a server), would it really be necessary? Wouldn't `/usr/bin` be fine?

And what is `/bin`? Why is this area usually used for installing scripts onto the terminal?

Comment: Read `man hier`. It's a local copy of the Filesystem Hieracy Standard.

Comment: To read `man hier` on Arch Linux you first need to install the `man-pages` package.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` is for programs that a normal user may run.

- The `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally.
- It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is updated.
- It may be used for programs and data that
  are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not found in `/usr`.
- Locally installed software must be placed within `/usr/local` rather than /usr unless it is being installed to
  replace or upgrade software in `/usr`.

This source helps explain the [filesystem hierarchy standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) on a deeper level.

You might find [this article on the use and abuse of `/usr/local/bin`](https://www.aplawrence.com/Opinion/religion.html) interesting as well.

Comment: Your first link seems to point to an outdated version of the FHS, version 2.3 of 2004. Seems in 2015 version 3.0 came out, which you can find [here](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml)

Answer (score 100):

> /usr/, I assume is the user of the computer.

Close.

Unix started out as a multi-user operating system, so it's not "the user," it's "the *users*," plural.

Before AT&T Unix [System V Release 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V#SVR4) (SVR4) came out in 1988 with its user management tools defaulting to creating user home directories in `/home`, the conventional location was `/usr`.¹ Your `$HOME` directory might have been `/usr/jfw` on a [System III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_III) box.

`/usr` also contained, then as now, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib`, etc. Experience showed that segregating the home directories was good system management practice, so with the `/home` policy change in SVR4, it left behind everything we now think of as belonging in `/usr`.

`/usr` still had a good reason to hold onto the name: what got left behind were files that didn't need to be available until the system was booted up far enough to support normal interactive use. That is to say, what was left behind were the *user*-focused parts of the OS. This meant that `/usr` could be on a different physical volume, which was a good thing back in the days of [92 MB hard disk drives the size of washing machines](https://web.archive.org/web/20200625181257/https://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/rp04.html).

Early Unix systems were careful to keep the core OS files out of `/usr` so that you could still boot into single-user mode² even if the `/usr` volume was unmountable for some reason. The root volume contained sufficient tools to get the `/usr` volume back online.

Several Unix flavors now disregard this old design principle since even small embedded systems have enough room for both the traditional root volume files *and* all of `/usr` on a single volume.³ Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Solaris and Cygwin symlink `/bin` to `/usr/bin` and `/lib` to `/usr/lib` so that there is no longer any difference between these directories.

> .../local/...obviously stands for the local computer...

Yes. It refers to the fact that files under `/usr/local` are supposed to be particular to that single system. Files that are in any way generic should live elsewhere.

This also has roots in the way Unix systems were commonly used decades ago when all this was standardized. Again, hard disks of the time were bulky, really expensive, and stored little by today's standards. To save money and space on disks, a computer lab full of Unix boxes would often share most of `/usr` over NFS or some other network file sharing protocol, so each box didn't have to have its own redundant copy.⁴ Files specific to a single box would go under `/usr/local`, which would be a separate volume from `/usr`.

This historical heritage is why it's still the default for most third-party Unix software to install into `/usr/local` when installed by hand. Most such software will let you install the package somewhere else, but by making a non-choice, you get the safe default, which doesn't interfere with other common install locations with more specific purposes.

There are good reasons to make software install somewhere else instead. Apple's macOS team does this when they build, say, `bash` from the [GNU Bash source code](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). They use `/` as the installation prefix, overriding the `/usr/local` default, so that Bash ends up in `/bin`.

Another example is the way older Linux systems segregated their GUI software into `/usr/X11R6`, to keep it separate from the traditional command line and [`curses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))-based software. This was done simply by overriding the default `/usr/local` prefix with `/usr/X11R6`.⁵

> And what is /bin?

It's short for "binary," which in this context means "a file that is not plain text." Most such files are [executables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) on a Unix box, so these two terms have become synonymous in some circles. ("Please build me a binary for RHEL 7, Fred.")

Text files on a Unix box live elsewhere: `/etc`, `/usr/include`, `/usr/share`, etc.

Once upon a time, even shell scripts — which are plain text files — were kept out of `bin` directories, but this line, too, has blurred. Today, `bin` directories typically contain any kind of executable file, whether strictly "binary" or not.⁶

---

**Footnotes and Digressions**:

1. The primitive nature of the user management tools prior to SVR4 meant that the `HOME=/usr/$NAME` scheme was merely documented as a convention, rather than enforced by software tools as a default.

   You can see this on page 4-8 of the "[AT&T Unix System V Release 3.2 System Administrator's Guide](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/att/unix/System_V_386_Release_3.2/UNIX_System_V_386_Release_3.2_System_Administrators_Guide_1989.pdf): here you see AT&T recommending the old `/usr/$NAME` scheme in the last major version of Unix before SVR4 came out.

   It was fairly common in older Unix systems for the system administrators to choose a different scheme that made more sense to them. People being people, that meant a lot of different schemes got invented.

   One scheme I came across before `/home/$NAME` became the standard was `/u/$NAME`.

   [Another system I used](http://www.nyx.net) in the early 1990s had so many users that they couldn't fit all the home directories onto a single physical volume, so they used a scheme like `/u1/$NAME`, `/u2/$NAME`, and so on, as I recall. Which disk your home directory ended up on was simply a matter of which one had space on it at the time your account was created.
2. You can boot a macOS box into single-user mode by holding down <kbd>Cmd-S</kbd> while it boots. Let go once the screen turns black and you see light gray text appear. It's like running under the Terminal, but it takes over the whole screen because the GUI hasn't started yet.

   Be careful, you're running as `root`.

   Type "exit" at the single-user root prompt to leave single-user mode and continue booting into multi-user GUI mode.
3. Unixy OSes that still *appear* to keep critical single-user mode files out of `/usr` may not, in fact, do so these days. I once rendered a FreeBSD 9 box unbootable by moving `/usr` to a ZFS volume. I forgot that the ZFS-on-root features didn't land until FreeBSD 10, creating a [Catch 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22): the OS needed files in `/usr` in order to mount `/usr`!

   That was bad enough, but if FreeBSD 9 were still keeping its single-user boot stuff out of `/usr`, I could have fixed it in place. Since it wouldn't boot even to single-user mode with `/usr` being unmountable, clearly that tradition had been violated somehow. I had to boot from a rescue CD to get that system back up again.
4. This is also where we get `/usr/share`: it segregates files that could be shared (e.g. over NFS) even between Unix boxes with different processor types. Typically, text files: man pages, the dictionary, etc.
5. "X11R6" referred to the version of the [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) underpinning Linux GUIs at the time this convention was prevalent. Linux systems generally stopped segregating the GUI software about the time X11R6 was replaced with [X.Org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server).
6. The original Unix systems kept their core shell scripts in `/etc` in order to avoid commingling them with the true binaries in `/bin`.

Comment: Loved that picture of washing machine!

Comment: @Warren, What are the notable OSes before System III?

Comment: @Pacerier: UNIX Versions 1 through 7, UNIX/32V, 1BSD through 4BSD not including the dot releases of 4BSD (4.1BSD was roughly contemporaneous with AT&T Unix System III), and PWB Unix. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix). Why do you ask, and what does it have to do with this question?

Comment: @Warren, Well, they might have affected the defacto "directory naming system" somehow

Comment: @Pacerier: I'll stand by my claim: there was no "standard" before System V, only conventions and local practices.

Comment: @WarrenYoung, So you mean 1983 is a turning point?

Comment: @Pacerier: Every year in computing history is a turning point for *something*. One of the many things that happened in 1983 in computing was that `/home` became a de facto standard. You seem to want to have an argument about it, but I can't see the point. This is just a thing that happened, and I believe I've isolated the point in time and the technology where it happened. What more is there to say about it?

Comment: @WarrenYoung, No I just think that [this other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/96420/87017) is much clearer: """/bin & /sbin are for vital programs for the OS, sbin being for administrators only""" and """/usr/bin & /usr/sbin are for not vital programs, sbin being for administrators only"""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68045/discussion-between-warren-young-and-pacerier).

Comment: @WarrenYoung, re "*There are good reasons*"; Eg?

Comment: @Pacerier: I gave an example in the very next sentence.

Comment: i thought /usr was short for "Unix system resources" , not "user" or "THE users"

Comment: @clockw0rk: That's a persistent myth, which as far as I can tell, has a single source in one of the early Linux HOWTO series documents. You will not find it in _any_ credible source prior to that, particularly not in any of the AT&T or BSD system documentation. **Please stop perpetuating it!**

Answer (score 15):

`/usr/local/bin` shows the UNIX-esque roots of the latest Mac OS (its BSD based under there).

- "usr" stands for UNIX System Resources.  This is the location that system programs and libraries are stored.
- "local" represents resources that were not shipped with the standard distribution and, usually, compiled and maintained on a per site basis.
- "bin" represents binary compiled executables.

This has morphed since the early implementations of UNIX to Linux and BSD, but the convention has stayed.  Now, `/usr/bin` would be for "main" or core programs and libraries where `/usr/local/bin` would be for add-on and non-critical programs and libraries.

Comment: I've been using Unix since shortly after the Berlin Wall fell, and I'd never heard the "Unix System Resources" expansion for "usr" until today; it is a backronym. "usr" got its name because it's where the user home directories were originally located. That is, if you had a login on an old System III box, your initial working directory would be `/usr/nzwulfin` by default. Another common scheme. before the SVR4 `/home` scheme took over, was `/u`. One system I used early on had so many users they needed multiple physical disks for user file storage, so they had things like `/u/d5/tangent`.

Comment: @Warren I hadn't heard it either and poked around Google for a while; it sounds like there are quite a few backronyms

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend referring to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure) for structure related questions in general, it will cover the basics.

To answer your question directly, however:

- /usr is, loosely, non-critical system libraries and executables
- /usr/local is, again loosely, for non-system libraries and executables

This is why you tend to find similar structure between the two; /usr/{,local/}{bin,sbin,lib}. Being new to the shell, that bit with the {}'s is a shell expansion. Try executing

```
ls -ld /usr/{,local/}{bin,sbin,lib}
```

from your local shell to see how it works.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/local/bin` is the most popular default location for executable files, especially open source ones.

This is however arguably a poor choice as, on Unix systems, `/usr` has been standardized in the early nineties to contain a hierarchy of files that belong to the operating system and thus can be shared by multiple systems using that OS.

As these files are static, the `/usr` file system can be mounted read-only. `/usr/local` is defeating this standard as it is by design local thus non shared, so needs to be read-write to allow local compilation and isn't part of the operating system. Too bad something like `/opt/local` wasn't chosen instead ...

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be helpful as well.

#### /usr/local

The original idea behind `/usr/local` was to have a separate ('local') '/usr' directory on every machine besides `/usr`, which might be just mounted read-only from somewhere else. It copies the structure of `/usr`.

These days, `/usr/local` is widely regarded as a good place in which to keep self-compiled or third-party programs. The `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is updated.

It may be used for programs and data that are shared among a group of hosts, but not found in `/usr`. Locally installed software must be placed within `/usr/local` rather than `/usr` unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software in `/usr`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `/usr/local` for commercial programs you might install such as Mathematica.  Place it in its own partition when you set up. When you upgrade your OS, this partition won't be disturbed and you won't have to re-install its contents. So use it for stuff you want to keep between OS upgrades.

Separately, make sure you give `/home` its own partition for this reason too.

Comment: Should commercial software not installed in a unix way go in /opt instead?