# Where should I put a standalone web app which doesn't require an external web server?

Tags: linux, webserver, directory-structure

I have a stand-alone web app, it's an executable file. At this point it doesn't require nginx or apache in front of it because it has a built-in webserver. Where should I put it on a server? In the directory of my user? Or in /opt/something or somewhere else?

Also, it's controlled by systemd.

Comment: Wherever you decide, it can be very useful to write a small script or makefile target that does the installation, including any `chmod` and so on, so you have a starting point for later re-use, or even better package it as an rpm or .deb, no matter how small it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, the location for this would be `/usr/local` (resp. `/usr/local/bin` if this is just one executable). See [What is /usr/local/bin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/what-is-usr-local-bin) and [What is the difference between /opt and /usr/local?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local) .

Comment: actually, it has a few config files as well.

Comment: Then I'd suggest `/usr/local/bin` for the executable, and a subdirectory `/usr/local/etc/yourappname` for the config files. Alternatively, executable and config files in a subdirectory `/usr/local/yourappname`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a packaged app, I would say opt.

My understanding is that `/usr/local` is more like an overlay to `/` whereas `/opt` is a place to put applications that fit in a single subdirectory.