# Why Python is located on 3 different location ? Which one should i keep and how to delete others?

Tags: linux-mint

Why Python is located on 3 different location ? Which one should i keep and how to delete others ?
I want to keep the python which will be used from globally and want to delete other version..

System - Linux-Mint(Cinnamon)

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's python3 ... have you checked for python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually only two different locations -- `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` so `/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3` is the same file. And you definitely shouldn't remove this one, this is the system version of Python and if you remove this one, you'll break your system (a lot of essential tools and applications are written in Python and they use this one).

The `/usr/local/bin/python3` is something you probably installed manually, this is a different (newer) version and is installed in `/usr/local` which is intended for [locally installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/what-is-usr-local-bin) software. If you want to remove this one, you should do it using the same tool/tutorial/steps you installed it.

Note: if you are developing using Python, you should use [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) to avoid messing with the system Python.